# Java CompletableFuture.runAsync recurrsion ... any potential risk?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

My requirement is to poll MongoDB every 30s for any data change in a collection. I have used Java CompletableFuture.runAsync to implement this feature as code captured below. I have test run the program for a day and it seems working fine.

My questions are:

1. Would there be any potential risk of OOM "stack overflow" exception if I keep running for long time?
2. My threadpool size is 3, from the log file I found that the first few 2 runs are using pool-1-thread-1 and pool-1-thread-2, from the third run and so on it keeps reusing pool-1-thread-3 for some time, then reuse pool-1-thread-1/pool-1-thread-2 for certain period of time... would there be any potential issue or is it normal?

   ```
   private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

   private void watch(){
       CompletableFuture<Void> watchForLeadershipChange = 
           CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> pollForChanges(), executor);
   }

   private void pollForChanges() {
       //Query MongoDB collection and do some logic

       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
       watch();
   }
   ```

Comment: Why not `ScheduledExecutorService`? Or just a `while()` loop?

Comment: As for the tasks being picked up by different poolthreads: Yes, it's normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***Would there be any potential risk of OOM "stack overflow" exception if I keep running for long time?*** No. While `pollForChanges()` calls `watch()`, the subsequent invocations of `pollForChanges()` are happening asynchronously in (probably) another thread. In either case it will always have a fresh stack pointer.
2. ***My threadpool size is 3, from the log file I found that the first few 2 runs…*** Which thread the `ExecutorService` chooses is an implementation detail of that `ExecutorService`. There is nothing odd or unexpected about the behavior you are observing.

All of that being said - this is a very roundabout way of doing something very trivial with a `ScheduledExecutorService` as was pointed out in comments:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
        () -> queryMongoAndDoSomeLogic(),
        0,
        30,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```